# Set default browser to be a new Firefox Private Browser window

Tags: default-programs, privacy, default-browser

When I select default applications, I can only choose my default browser as chrome or vanilla Firefox.

[image: Only Firefox]

I'd like my default browser to open whatever link in a new private window.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To always use Private Browsing mode in Firefox take the following steps:

1. Open Firefox and navigate to the hamburger menu (3 parallel line
   icon top right of FF)
2. Select `Settings` then the `Privacy and Security` sub menu.
3. Scroll down to `History` then using the drop down menu select change
   the current default to `Use Custom Settings`
4. With “Custom Settings” selected, look beneath the drop-down menu.
   Check the box beside “Always Use Private Browsing Mode.”
5. Upon clicking the checkbox, Firefox will ask to restart the browser.
   Click “Restart Firefox Now.”
6. Once Firefox restarts, private browsing mode will always be enabled.
7. To confirm this, return to Options → Privacy & Security → History.
   There should be a check mark in the box beside “Always Use Private
   Browsing Mode.”

There will be no need to change anything in the `Default Applications` menu and always remember to close all FF windows when you are done to preserve your navigation history privacy.

[reference](https://www.howtogeek.com/676925/how-to-always-start-mozilla-firefox-in-private-browsing-mode/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My use case is a little different though--I don't want to clobber firefox in general. I have a general firefox session I am happy to keep not private.  I just want new links I click on not to use it---I'd prefer any link I click on specifically to be sequestered to a new private window.

Comment: In which event you may need to set up different profiles [see](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1262935)

Comment: @Mittenchops please edit your question to make that clear. Also explain how the system can know when you want something private and when you don't. I imagine you know about right click on a link -> "open link in new private window" right?

Answer (score 0):

### Copy the existing desktop file to your user's profile

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-private.desktop
```

### Edit that file

```
# or your preferred editor, i.e. gedit for graphical editing
nano ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-private.desktop
```

Add the lines

```ini
NoDisplay=true
Hidden=true
```

immediately after `[Desktop Entry]`, so the file will start like:

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
NoDisplay=true
Hidden=true
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox
GenericName=Web Browser
```

Scroll down a bit to find `Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox %u`. Replace it with `Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox --private-window %u`.

### Reload desktop files

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```

### Make it your default browser

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox-private.desktop
```

---

GNOME may be confused and show multiple Firefox icons. If that happens, log out and log back in, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then type `r`, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.